# Configuring WWW prefix and HTTPS using Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want Nginx to redirect all connections to: `https://domain.xyz` (remove www prefix if needed and always force https), so that for example:
`http://wwww.domain.xyz/param` and `domain.xyz/param` should redirect me to `https://domain.xyz`. To do that i made the following config in default server:

```
server {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
}
```

and "sub servers":

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   
        server_name domain.xyz; 
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {

        server_name subdomain.domain.xyz;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

So i assumed the default server will do both for me (remove www prefix and force https), however when i try to open `www.domain.xyz` I'm getting this error in Chrome console:

```
Redirecting navigation www.domain.xyz -> domain.xyz because the server presented a certificate valid for domain.xyz but not for www.domain.xyz. To disable such redirects launch Chrome with the following flag: --disable-features=SSLCommonNameMismatchHandling
```

Except that everything works as expected. Also, as you can see i used letsencrypt to generate certs (for domain.xyz and subdomain.domain.xyz -- without wwww prefix (!) -- maybe that is the reason). So to sum it up:

1. Is my config correct for the things i want to achieve?
2. Should i be worried about that Chrome message?

Comment: Based on your description, the issue does seem to be that you don't have a cert for www.domain.xyz. The fact that Chrome is doing this at all is interesting, but I don't think should be relied on. It seems that it's being "nice" to do the auto redirect. You should ensure that you have "www" included in your certs.

Comment: You handle two of the three redirect cases. The third case is `https://www` to `https://non-www` which is not handled by any of your server blocks.

Comment: @RichardSmith hmm... you sure? My "sub-servers" handle requests on `https://non-www` (domain.xyz and subdomain.domain.xyz), all the rest get to default server which redirects to "sub-servers". I've just tested and it works good. Also i will try to generate cert including www prefix.

Comment: Your first server block listens on port 80 only. So connections to 443 must be handled by one of the other server blocks which do not appear to include an implicit redirect.

Comment: You are right... Any ideas how to fix this? I mean is there any general way, like with HTTP? Because if i add `listen 443 default_server` i also need to include ssl cert. What if certs are different for different server names?